# UIStoryboard relationship segue "root view" hides tabbar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard

I've inherited project which main view based on `UITabBarController` with two tabs, each is `UINavigationController` with `root view controller` connected via *Relationship "root view controller" segue*. I need to add 3d one.

I do the same for it - add `UINavigationController` scene, create relationship to `UITabBarController` as "view controllers". Then create segue from this new navigation controller to needed `root view controller`. It works, but when I select this 3d tab, `UITabBar` disappears. What could be happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was trivial... IB flag "Hide Bottom Bar on Push" actually hides tabbar not only when pushed, but always for this view controller. Very strange behavior btw, seems like a bug in SDK.